# How to filter DropDown list by logged in User in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

How to filter the dropdown list, and I need to take the name of logged-in User.

In controller I have this code:

```
var agentBR = (Session["aID"]);
ViewBag.AgentID = new SelectList(db.tbl_agenti.Where(x => x.aID.Equals("agentBR")), "aID", "agent_ime");
```

but not work, session id ok, and in the browser, I have this error:

> **DbComparisonExpression requires arguments with comparable types.**
>
> **Description:** An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> **Exception Details:** System.ArgumentException: DbComparisonExpression requires arguments with comparable types.

Source Error:

```
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.AgentID, "AgentID", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })

**@Html.DropDownList("AgentID", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })**

@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AgentID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
```

Comment: Is `aID` string type ?

Comment: aID is int, primarikey in database table.

Comment: What is inside `Session["aID"]` ?

Comment: When the user LogIn, session if from Login. Then take Session["aID"] and Session["agent_name"], now i need just aID

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This part of your code in the `Where` method

```
x.aID.Equals("agentBR")
```

Is trying to filter the records where the `aID` property value is matching to the value passed in the `Equals` method. You mentioned that aID is `int` type, but you are passing a string `"agentBR"` to Equals method for the comparison, hence getting the type mismatch error.

You should try to pass the same type.

Assuming the value stored inside `Session["aID"]` is a valid int32 value, you may read that to an int variable and use that in your where clause to compare against your `aID` property which is of same `int` type.

```
int agentId=0;
if(Session["aID"]!=null)
{
   agentId = Convert.ToInt32(Session["aID"]);
}
var agents = new SelectList(db.tbl_agenti
                               .Where(x => x.aID.Equals(agentId)), "aID", "agent_ime");
ViewBag.AgentID  = agents;
```